# Android: Buttons are not reacting to clicks

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating a bunch of plus and minus buttons for a data collection app. I'm using a state machine.

When I press the buttons in my app the `TextView` that diplays the number is supposed to change, but it doesn't. What did I do wrong?

This is the relevant code:

```
package com.example.scoutingapp3250;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.icu.lang.UCharacter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import 
com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.zxing.client.android.Intents;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static String finalOutput;
public static StringBuilder stringBuilder;

public enum ScanState {
    scanning,
    empty,
    stopped
}

ScanState scanState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onResume();
    findViewById(R.id.minusButtonAutoPowerPortBottom).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.plusButtonAutoPowerPortBottom).setOnClickListener(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkForms();
            //if (checkForms();return;void)
            openActivity2();
        }
    });
}

public void checkForms() {
    scanState = ScanState.scanning;
    ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    final int childCount = linearLayout.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View element = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        switch (scanState) {
            case scanning:
                if (element instanceof EditText) {
                    EditText editText = (EditText) element;
                    if (editText.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                        scrollView.scrollTo(0, editText.getTop() + 10);
                        scanState = ScanState.empty;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                if (element instanceof RadioGroup) {
                    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) element;
                    RadioButton radioButton = findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                    if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
                        scrollView.scrollTo(0, radioGroup.getTop());
                        scanState = ScanState.empty;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                scanState = ScanState.stopped;
                break;
            case empty:
                break;
            case stopped:
                break;
        }

    }
}

public void openActivity2() {
    output();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QrCodeGenerator.class);
    intent.putExtra("data", stringBuilder.toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void openPitScout() {
    Intent pitScout = new Intent (MainActivity.this, PitScouter.class);
    startActivity(pitScout);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    /* Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
       as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml. */
    int id = item.getItemId();


    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.pitScoutSheet) {
        openPitScout();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

private void addInt(int stateID) {
    TextView tView = findViewById(stateID);
    int value = Integer.parseInt(tView.getText().toString());
    value += 1;
    String temp = Integer.toString(value); tView.setText(temp);
    //tView.setText(Integer.toString(value));
}

private void subInt(int stateID) {
    TextView tView = findViewById(stateID);
    int value = Integer.parseInt(tView.getText().toString());
    value -= 1;
    String temp = Integer.toString(value); tView.setText(temp);
    //tView.setText(Integer.toString(value));
}

    public void output () {
        EditText scoutName = findViewById(R.id.editSN);
        TextView teamNumber = findViewById(R.id.editTN);
        EditText matchNumber = findViewById(R.id.editMatchNumber);
        RadioGroup alliance = findViewById(R.id.alliance);
        RadioButton allianceI = findViewById(alliance.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        RadioGroup driverStation = findViewById(R.id.driverStation);
        RadioButton driverStationI = findViewById(driverStation.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        RadioGroup crossLine = findViewById(R.id.crossLine);
        RadioButton crossLineI = findViewById(crossLine.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        TextView autoPowerPortBottom = findViewById(R.id.autoPowerPortBottomDisplay);
        TextView autoPowerPortOuter = findViewById(R.id.autoPowerPortOuterDisplay);
        TextView autoDroppedPowerCells = findViewById(R.id.autoDroppedPowerCellsDisplay);
        RadioGroup autoConflict = findViewById(R.id.autoConflict);
        RadioButton autoConflictS = findViewById(autoConflict.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        TextView powerPortBottom = findViewById(R.id.powerPortBottomDisplay);
        TextView powerPortOuter = findViewById(R.id.powerPortOuterDisplay);
        TextView droppedPowerCells = findViewById(R.id.droppedPowerCellsDisplay);
        RadioGroup rotationControl = findViewById(R.id.rotationControlGroup);
        RadioButton rotationControlI = findViewById(rotationControl.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        RadioGroup stageReached = findViewById(R.id.stageReachedGroup);
        RadioButton stageReachedI = findViewById(stageReached.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        CheckBox boxTrench = findViewById(R.id.boxTrench);
        CheckBox boxCenter = findViewById(R.id.boxCenter);
        CheckBox boxOnTheirSide = findViewById(R.id.boxOnTheirSide);
        RadioGroup climb = findViewById(R.id.climb);
        RadioButton climbS = findViewById(climb.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        RadioGroup multiClimb = findViewById(R.id.multiClimb);
        RadioButton multiClimbS = findViewById(multiClimb.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        RadioGroup driverSkill = findViewById(R.id.driverSkill);
        RadioButton driverSkillI = findViewById(driverSkill.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        RadioGroup focusOnDefense = findViewById(R.id.groupFocusOnDefense);
        RadioButton focusOnDefenseI = findViewById(focusOnDefense.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        TextView beached = findViewById(R.id.beachedDisplay);
        TextView disabled = findViewById(R.id.disabledDisplay);
        TextView died = findViewById(R.id.diedDisplay);
        TextView fouls = findViewById(R.id.foulDisplay);
        TextView techFouls = findViewById(R.id.techFoulDisplay);
        EditText notes = findViewById(R.id.editNotes);

        String[] outputString = new String[]{
                scoutName.getText().toString(),
                teamNumber.getText().toString(),
                matchNumber.getText().toString(),
                allianceI.getText().toString(),
                driverStationI.getText().toString(),
                crossLineI.getText().toString(),
                autoPowerPortBottom.getText().toString(),
                autoPowerPortOuter.getText().toString(),
                autoDroppedPowerCells.getText().toString(),
                autoConflictS.getText().toString(),
                powerPortBottom.getText().toString(),
                powerPortOuter.getText().toString(),
                droppedPowerCells.getText().toString(),
                rotationControlI.getText().toString(),
                stageReachedI.getText().toString(),
                boxTrench.getText().toString(),
                boxCenter.getText().toString(),
                boxOnTheirSide.getText().toString(),
                climbS.getText().toString(),
                multiClimbS.getText().toString(),
                driverSkillI.getText().toString(),
                focusOnDefenseI.getText().toString(),
                beached.getText().toString(),
                disabled.getText().toString(),
                died.getText().toString(),
                fouls.getText().toString(),
                techFouls.getText().toString(),
                notes.getText().toString()
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < outputString.length; i++) {
            stringBuilder.append(outputString[i]);
            stringBuilder.append(", ");
        }
    }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.minusButtonAutoPowerPortBottom:
            subInt(R.id.autoPowerPortBottomDisplay);
            break;
        case R.id.plusButtonAutoPowerPortBottom:
            addInt(R.id.autoPowerPortBottomDisplay);
            break;

        case R.id.minusButtonAutoPowerPortOuter:
            subInt(R.id.autoPowerPortOuterDisplay);
            break;
        case R.id.plusButtonAutoPowerPortOuter:
            addInt(R.id.autoPowerPortOuterDisplay);
            break;

        case R.id.minusAutoDroppedPowerCells:
            subInt(R.id.autoDroppedPowerCellsDisplay);
            break;
        case R.id.plusAutoDroppedPowerCells:
            addInt(R.id.autoDroppedPowerCellsDisplay);
            break;

        case R.id.minusPowerPortBottom:
            subInt(R.id.powerPortBottomDisplay);
            break;
        case R.id.plusPowerPortBottom:
            addInt(R.id.powerPortBottomDisplay);
            break;

        case R.id.minusPowerPortOuter:
            subInt(R.id.powerPortOuterDisplay);
            break;
        case R.id.plusPowerPortOuter:
            addInt(R.id.powerPortOuterDisplay);
            break;

        case R.id.minusDroppedPowerCells:
            subInt(R.id.droppedPowerCellsDisplay);
            break;
        case R.id.plusDroppedPowerCells:
            addInt(R.id.droppedPowerCellsDisplay);
            break;

        case R.id.minusBeached:
            subInt(R.id.beachedDisplay);
            break;
        case R.id.plusBeached:
            addInt(R.id.beachedDisplay);
            break;

        case R.id.minusDisabled:
            subInt(R.id.disabledDisplay);
            break;
        case R.id.plusDisabled:
            addInt(R.id.disabledDisplay);
            break;

        case R.id.minusDied:
            subInt(R.id.minusDied);
            break;
        case R.id.plusDied:
            addInt(R.id.plusDied);
            break;

        case R.id.minusFouls:
            subInt(R.id.foulDisplay);
            break;
        case R.id.plusFoul:
            addInt(R.id.foulDisplay);
            break;

        case R.id.minusTechFoul:
            subInt(R.id.techFoulDisplay);
            break;
        case R.id.plusTechFoul:
            addInt(R.id.techFoulDisplay);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

XML repeated for each different function(i.e bottoPowerPort vs ad died count)

```xml
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewAutoPowerPortBottom"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/autoPowerPortBottom"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textColor"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minusButtonAutoPowerPortBottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/autoPowerPortBottomDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textColor"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plusButtonAutoPowerPortBottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewAutoPowerPortOuter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/autoPowerPortOuter"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textColor"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minusButtonAutoPowerPortOuter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/autoPowerPortOuterDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textColor"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plusButtonAutoPowerPortOuter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewAutoDroppedPowerCells"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/autoDroppedPowerCells"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textColor"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minusAutoDroppedPowerCells"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/autoDroppedPowerCellsDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textColor"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plusAutoDroppedPowerCells"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"/>
```

Comment: please share more information. maybe log...

Comment: Sometimes IDE complains about `someView.setText();` function with type conversion. Can you try to change this `tView.setText(Integer.toString(value));` line to this `String temp = Integer.toString(value); tView.setText(temp);`

Comment: the logcat just says"
2020-01-21 14:57:42.409 27469-27469/com.example.scoutingapp3250 I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
2020-01-21 14:57:42.508 27469-27469/com.example.scoutingapp3250 I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN" for everytime i touch a button

Comment: @TeachMeJava it still doesn't work. It also still says the same thing in logcat

Comment: I am assuming you didn't forget to set these clicks to every button :D

Comment: @Emin Guliev doesnt the state machine do that...?

Comment: You should remove onResume() call in your onCreate() method as well

Comment: Why do you say that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from your response and comments, you did it a little wrong.
**`onClick()`** method is not called for every Widget in your layout tree automatically.

What you did is implementing **`View.OnClickListener`** to your activity.
So basically your should tell all buttons/views you click to use implemented **`onClick()`** method. In your case you need something like this in **`onCreate()`** method:

```
findViewById(R.id.minusButtonAutoPowerPortBottom).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.plusButtonAutoPowerPortBottom).setOnClickListener(this);
...
```

Comment: when i did that it gives me this error when it opens(sorry im kinda new so I dont know too much)"        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.scoutingapp3250.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
"

Comment: added it to the OP

Comment: Okay, I got you. Your need to add these after setContentView. 
And not only for 2 buttons, but all you want to make clickable :)

Comment: Thank you so much man!! I can't believe I've been sitting here like an idiot trying to figure this out and it was as simple as that!